# Oracle TNS names configuration

Tags: oracle

I've edited added new TNS name to `tnsnames.ora`.
Toad for Oracle started to work at once. SQL Plus doesn't work even after logoff/logon, the same problem with my build scripts.

Getting the error: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified

How could I fix it?

Comment: have you added a TNS_ADMIN environment variable?

Comment: no, let me try...

Comment: @MykhayloAdamovych:You need to put your tnsnames.ora in TNS_ADMIN, and set enviornment variable for TNS_ADMIN

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various methods  of achieving this ,one of them as suggested by `Yasir`.
Please follow the below steps:

1. Close toad/sqlplus
2. Create a folder `TNS_ADMIN`
3. Add tnsnames.ora in TNS_ADMIN
4. Add TNS_ADMIN in enviornment variable.
5. Open Toad/Sqlplus and login

I think this will be very clear ,cheer

Answer (score 1):

Just put your Oracle Net files (`tnsnames.ora`, `sqlnet.ora` etc.) to `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` directory.

[Local Naming Parameters (tnsnames.ora)](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/network.112/e10835/tnsnames.htm#i433681):

> By default, the `tnsnames.ora` file is located in the
>   `ORACLE_HOME/network/admin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

The safest and simplest way to add a tns entry to an oracle client is to use the wizard. 
run `netca` on the command line and fill in the necessary fields step by step. if you need to add parameters edit what the wizard created.

Comment: Or Oracle Net Manager (`netmgr`) which provides slightly more advanced settings. ;-)